# Fill firebase database using prisma.scheme

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb, firebase, backend

In my project im using prisma + mongodb but i want to migrate to the firebase
In`schema.prisma` is the schema of the collections which are going to be in my database something like that

```
model User {
  id              String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name            String?
}
```

and using `npx prisma db push` im pushing all this models as collections to the my mongodb

so for my migrating i want to know is there is some method or way to do so using firebase, can i push this prisma.scheme to the firebase just like its pushed to the mongodb ?